# Como alterar a cor do menu ao passar o mouse em cima

Tags: css

Implementei um CSS no meu sistema onde eu passo o mouse por cima do menu e exibe os submenus.

Esta é a CSS pra passar o mouse por cima dos menus

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu
{ 
    display: block; 
}
```

só que é o seguinte, quando eu passo o mouse por cima destes menus eu gostaria que a cor alterasse como se fosse a do clica como mostra as fotos abaixo:

Clicando no Menu:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem clicar no menu:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só definir a propriedade `background-color` usando o seletor `ul.nav li.dropdown:hover`.

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover
{ 
    background-color: algumTomDeAzulAqui;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu
{ 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: com o background-color o submenu que muda de cor

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo Esqueci de tirar o final do seletor, tenta dessa forma

Comment: retirando o  ul.dropdown-menu o menu fica com a cor correta porem o submenu não aparece

Comment: Não, @LeonardoMacedo Você tem que manter os dois CSS.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! daqui 5 minutos eu coloco como positivo aqui!

Comment: eu ja coloquei como positivo mais como é relacionado a questão queria saber mais uma coisa. Eu achei uma coisa aqui também, não sei se isso pode ser feito por css também, quando eu clico no no menu e passo o mouse no outro, o menu que cliquei não some, e abre o que passei o mouse por css eu consigo arrumar isso ?

Comment: Conseguir consegue, mas, embora tenha relação com a pergunta atual, acho que é outra coisa. Seria melhor abrir uma nova pergunta, não acha? Até porque, vai ser necessário um exemplo mais detalhado do menu...

Comment: beleza eu vou abrir aqui

Comment: criei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211448/passar-mouse-no-menu-e-exibir-submenus