# Passar mouse no menu e exibir submenus

Tags: css

estou com o seguinte problema em meu sistema.

Coloquei um css nos menus, onde eu passo o mouse sobre os menus e exibe os submenus vinculados a eles.

**CSS**

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover
{ 
    background-color: #0c7cd5;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu
{ 
    display: block; 
}
```

o meu problema é o seguinte, quando eu clico em um submenu ele fica fixo, porem quando eu passo o mouse em outro menu, ele exibe porem não esconde no qual eu cliquei, segue a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Tem que postar o código do menu para podermos analisar uma provável solução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode utilizar o JQUERY on focusout, on focusin ou blur com a seguinte função :

```
   $("#id-do-componente").on("focusout",function() {

          $('#id-do-componente-a-remover').addClass("id-da-classe");

    }
```

Ou seja quando seu componente principal perder o foco que seria o centro você irá adicionar a classe referente a formatação que esconde ele. Você pode criar no CSS por exemplo e aplicar na classe da div uma classe.

```
<div class="menu-remove">
</div>
```

no css :

```
.menu-remove{
  display:none
}
```

ou seja nesse caso nossa função jquery ficaria :

```
$("#id-do-componente").on("focusout",function() {

              $('#id-do-componente-a-remover').addClass("menu-remove");

        }
```

O focusin funciona caso o componente "ganhe a atenção", ou seja um click de mouse ou um tab até ele, já o blur é quando se perde qualquer foco, a estrutura so mudaria para essa forma :

```
$("#id-do-componente").blur(function() {

                  $('#id-do-componente-a-remover').addClass("menu-remove");

            }
```

---

Código Exemplo;

código php/html:

```
<div id="botao-centro">
   <div id="conteudo-centro">
   //Conteudo do menu do botão centro
   </div>
</div>
```

código CSS:

```
#botao-centro{
  //Conteudo css botao centro
}
#conteudo-centro {
 //Conteudo css menu centro
}
#conteudo-centro .menu-remove{
  display:none,
}
```

código jquery:

```
 $("#botao-centro").on("focusout",function() {

          $('#conteudo-centro').addClass("menu-remove");

    }
```

Comment: não funcionou coloquei dois ids nos meus menos id="centro" e id="usuario" ficou assim

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#usuario").on("focusout", function () {

            $('#centro').addClass("menu-remove");
        });
    });

Comment: No caso o id-do-componente tem que ser o ID do centro, correto, e id-do-componente-a-remover tem que ser o id do conteúdo do menu. Se o id do conteudo do menu é vamos supor : menu, voce vai criar um css  #menu .menu-remove { display:none} ou seja, quando você adicionar essa classe ele para de aparecer, e isso ocorrera quado o focus do centro for perdido, entendeu ?

Comment: não entendi desculpa, poderia me explicar melhor ?

Comment: ha sim agora entendi

Comment: não funcionou o codigos

Comment: eu coloquei um código exemplo em cima. Repare nos ids das divs, e no que foi escrito no css, eu coloquei no css uma edição para #conteudo-centro .menu-remove{} se você reparar essa classe não existe no código php nem html, porque eu só vou adiciona-la quando o botão centro perder o foco, é isso que o jquery está fazendo, ou seja assim que perder o foco adicione a classe menu-remove, sendo assim ele pegara a formatação do estilo css #conteudo-centro .menu-remove que no caso está tirando o display de todo conteudo

Comment: Ahh já ia me esquecendo em vez de usar o addClass no jquery utilize o .toggleClass(), ele irá remover caso esteja adicionado, e adicionar caso esteja removido, se não você terá que ficar tratando o focusin e focusout para adicionar e remover as classes. tem uma doc aqui para te ajudar também nessa questão de adicionar ou remover classes com jquery https://tableless.com.br/manipulacao-de-classes-com-jquery/    esse artigo a seguir explica bem isso que estou tentando te passar : http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/basicos-jquery-adicionar-e-tirar-classe-css.html

Comment: inclusive utiliza os eventos mouseover e mouseout  que tratam se o mouse estiver em cima ou se sair, será até melhor utilizar esse.